# Display past dates before the year 1800

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a system for history events. It's showing the date using this

```
    date("j F, Y", strtotime($row['dated']));
```

But when I try: `21 Oct 1877`, it's showing `31 December, 1969`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: That looks like PHP, not MySQL.

Comment: (also, 1877 > 1800. Did you mean "below 1900"?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that

`$date = new DateTime($row['dated']);

echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

from here http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Answer (score 3):

You can ask MySQL to format the date the way you want so that you don't have to convert the formatted date to a timestamp then back to a formatted date.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: if i am fetching all data from a table called history what should sql query

Comment: Where you currently have the name of the date column, replace it with DATE_FORMAT(column_name, 'format string'). Refer to the linked manual page.

Comment: $query = sprintf("SELECT id, title, description, DATE_FORMAT(dated, '%e %M %Y') AS dated, cat, img, is_indian, updated, wiki, u_id  
                        FROM `events` 
                      WHERE 
                        MONTH(dated) = '%s' 
                      AND DAYOFMONTH(dated) = '%s' 
                        ;", 
                        mysql_real_escape_string($month), 
                        mysql_real_escape_string($date));

Comment: You should call the formatted column something other than `dated` since you use `dated` elsewhere in the query.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that `strtotime` converts the dates to the unix_timestamp, which is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. On unix_timestamp '0', it was still 31 December 1969 in USA.

Like @Dan Grossman told you, try to get the right format directly from MySQL. For example:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dated, '%d %M, %Y')
FROM history
```

Comment: how i can fix this, what should i have to use instead date("j F, Y", strtotime($row['dated']));

Comment: Dan Grossman has a good idea with letting MySQL format the date you want to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this MySQL, I'd suggest to use the `DATE` or `DATETIME` types for representing a date/date and time, as the UNIX timestamp has severe range limitations (can only represent dates between years 1901-2038, as opposed to `DATE`'s 1001-9999).

[Straight from the manual page of strtotime](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

> Note:
>
> The valid range of a timestamp is
>   typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901
>   20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038
>   03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates
>   that correspond to the minimum and
>   maximum values for a 32-bit signed
>   integer.) Additionally, not all
>   platforms support negative timestamps,
>   therefore your date range may be
>   limited to no earlier than the Unix
>   epoch. This means that e.g. dates
>   prior to Jan 1, 1970 will not work on
>   Windows, some Linux distributions, and
>   a few other operating systems. PHP
>   5.1.0 and newer versions overcome this limitation though.

In other words, UNIX timestamp is a signed 32-bit integer, and thus can only express cca 137 year span (1901-2038). If you want to do this in PHP, you should be looking at something like the [Calendar](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/book.calendar.php) functions.

Probably a better solution would be to use the MySQL's `DATETIME` type (instead of whatever string type you seem to be using), and use the `DATE_FORMAT()` to format the date.

Note also that various countries have switched to today's most common Gregorian calendar at various times - e.g. Russia was still using the Julian calendar in the 19th century (several days' worth of difference between the two).

Answer (score 0):

Piskvor and eumiro described why this happens, so i won't repeat that. what you *could* do to avoid this is to write your own litte function to format the date - just use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php) to get all parts of your date and rebuild the needet format from that parts like this:

```
list($year,$month,$day,$hour,$minute,$second) = explode('-',str_replace(array(' ',':'),'-',$row['dated']);
$output = "$day $month, $year";
```

this isn't perfect jet, it outputs the date as number - but you get the idea (you could use an array for storing the monthnames and output `$monthname[$month]` instead of `$month`)

**but:** also, you could let the database format the date for you, so you just have to output the result - i think this wich would be the best idea (i don't know the syntax out of my head, ask google for that)